# Get the hexadecimal representation of an int in python

Tags: python-2.7, hex

What's the easiest way in python to convert an integer to a string of its hexadecimal representation in python. As an example, I want foo s.t:

```
>>> foo(10)
'a'
>>> foo(17)
'11'
```

I could write a function to do this, but it seems like something that should be relatively easy to do with built-ins.

Comment: There's a builtin called `hex` strangely enough... :p Or use `format(value, 'X')`

Comment: A Google search would have answered this question without your having to post here. Think about that next time.

Comment: I was searching for about 10 minutes and pretty much every result involved getting hexadecimal bytes (using chr). But I guess I'll try harder next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
hex(65)
```

It will return the base 16 0x.. version for you.

Replace 65 with your variable name or another number.